# SharePoint 2013 restrict user level permission for particular folder

Tags: 2013, permissions

I have single document library with multiple folders.
Users/groups involved in that document library are:

1. Admin group-full control
2. HR department group-contribute level permission
3. Employee group- edit level permission.

Employee group has contained more than 100 users.
if user1 login means, they can see only their assigned folders and documents.
Like this we have to restrict all user.how to make it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also give folder level permissionin the same way you gave for Library level.
Click **...** next to folder for which you want to give unique permission
Share With -> Stop inheriting permission. Then remove and add permission for giving permission to that perticular folder.
[image: One][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihhfe.png)
[[image: Advanced]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihhfe.png)
[[image: Stop]][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b98Y2.png)

Comment: i know this option. i want another way to assign the folder to users

Comment: Alternate way is , you can create different views according to your requirement and restrict view by using target audience option.